# Android: XML Layout where parts dynamically overlay

Tags: android, xml, layout, overlay

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic overlay layout, better explain in this mockup I just created:

[image: Mockup of layout]

I have no idea where do start. I'd love to see some sample code on how to achieve that!
Thanks!

Comment: Add the TextView & ImageView into the listview header and the buttons into the ListView footer and it will work like that. The ListView's scroll will manipulate the entire layout.

Comment: Thanks! There's one thing I didn't explain correctly. The image (in green) has to block itself. So only the blue part can disappear. Does that fit into your methodology?

Comment: What do you mean by has to block itself? Either way the ListView has a built in ScrollView and it will scroll and take the items above and below into account.

Comment: So I want the textView to disappear when I scroll bottom, but I want the ImageView to remain persistent, no matter how far you scroll down in the listview. Sort of a staged scroll

Comment: Oh. That's a little different. Seems overly complicated. You should experiment with nested layouts in that case and see what you can come up with. Or call the onScrollListener and stop scrolling when the ImageView is at the top of the screen.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, I'm trying to get inspired from all the HTML5 designs we can see on some websites. I read some documentation about the ScrollView and they discourage to use it with a ListView... I'm kinda stuck

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a `<ScrollView>` ?

Cause if want you want is to display content in the app and you want the user to be able to scroll through the content, you use `<ScrollView>` , you only need to add all of your content between  the `<ScrollView>`  tags: like this

```
   <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <!-- Your layouts-->
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
       <!--The content you want to add-->
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_example" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_example"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

        <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/listview_example"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
         </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to put listview inside a scrollview. it's gonna mess up the scroll action and actually the height of the listview in a scrollview will be like uncontrollable ...it will display like wrap_content